# Как открыть книгу fb2 формата android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fb2

Вопрос собственно простой. Как и чем можно открыть fb2 формат, столь популярный вокруг. Мне не удалось найти библиотеки или чего-нибудь такого под android. Как работать с этими файлами?

Comment: Это просто подвид xml.

Comment: на гитхабе есть достаточно опенсорсных ридеров под андоид, можно посмотреть, как они устроены (включая известный FBReader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообщем-то мне удалось найти приложеньку, реализующую парсинг и отображение, причем маленькую и без апфускации. Код не то чтобы написан прилежно, но вариант очень хороший на мой взгляд:

https://github.com/bord81/LookBook_fb2_reader